# D3.js - cross-match arrays to style rects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a calendar orientation of rects appended. Each rect has a `.datum()` that is simply a date, like: `08/20/2020`. There is one rect for each day of the year.

Separately, I have a shorter array of objects that contain dates in their values. For example:

```
var dateData = [
{day:01/20/2020},
{day:04/21/2020},
{day:08/20/2020}
];
```

I want to cross-reference `dataData` when I append and style the rects during creation so that the rects whose dates are contained in `dateData` are blue and those not within that array of objects are gray. Here is my attempt:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect.day")
    .data(function(d, i) { return d3.timeDays(d, new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 1)); })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("rx", 3).attr("ry", 3) // rounded corners
    .style('fill', function(d) {dateData.filter(e => new Date(e.day) === d).length > 0 ? "#003366":"#d9d9d9"})
    //.attr("fill", '#eaeaea') // default light grey fill
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (day(d) * cellSize) + (day(d) * cellMargin) + cellMargin; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellSize) + ((week(d) - week(new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),1))) * cellMargin) + cellMargin ; })
```

However, this resulted in all rects rendering as black.

No errors thrown.

### Question

Is my approach fundamentally flawed, and is there a way to remedy the logic?

Comment: Couple typos, you currently don't have date strings: `01/20/2020`, intead of `"01/20/2020"`, you also need to return a colour for the fill (they are black as you don't return any value). Lastly, a separate issue, to compare dates see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/7106086).

Comment: @AndrewReid Yea, left out the `return` that was a big oversight. Fixed with your suggestion of `.getTime()` Thanks!